# retrieve images ,name etc from firebase

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve data(image ,name ,phone) from  firebase data base. but search bar is not working. nothing happened  when entered some text...

SearchBarActivity.java

```
public class SearchBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText search_edit_text;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
ArrayList<String> userNameList;
ArrayList<String> profilePicList;
SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_bar);
    search_edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    /*
    * Create a array list for each node you want to use
    * */
    fullNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    userNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    profilePicList = new ArrayList<>();
    search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                setAdapter(s.toString());
            }/* else {

                * Clear the list when editText is empty
                *
                fullNameList.clear();
                userNameList.clear();
                profilePicList.clear();
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
            }
        */}
    });
}

private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {
    mDatabaseRef.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            /*
            * Clear the list for every new search
            * */
            fullNameList.clear();
            userNameList.clear();
            profilePicList.clear();
            recyclerview.removeAllViews();
            int counter = 0;

            /*
            * Search all users for matching searched string
            * */
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String uid = snapshot.getKey();
                String full_name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String user_name = snapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class);
                String profile_pic = snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);

                if (full_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                    fullNameList.add(full_name);
                    userNameList.add(user_name);
                    profilePicList.add(profile_pic);
                    counter++;
                } else if (user_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                    fullNameList.add(full_name);
                    userNameList.add(user_name);
                    profilePicList.add(profile_pic);
                    counter++;
                }

                /*
                * Get maximum of 15 searched results only
                * */
                if (counter == 15)
                    break;
            }

            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchBarActivity.this, fullNameList, userNameList, profilePicList);
            recyclerview.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

SearchAdapter.java

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
ArrayList<String> userNameList;
ArrayList<String> profilePicList;
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView profileImage;
    TextView full_name, user_name;
    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        profileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageUrl);
        full_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        user_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    }
}

public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> fullNameList, ArrayList<String> userNameList, ArrayList<String> profilePicList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fullNameList = fullNameList;
    this.userNameList = userNameList;
    this.profilePicList = profilePicList;
}
@Override
public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.full_name.setText(fullNameList.get(position));
    holder.user_name.setText(userNameList.get(position));    Glide.with(context).load(profilePicList.get(position)).into(holder.profileImage);
    holder.full_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Full Name Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fullNameList.size();
}
```

Gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

i also tried  glide 4.0.0

activity_search_bar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Search Text..." />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

list-layout.xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageUrl"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full name goes here"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User name goes here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know what's Wrong ..there is no error ..... i  think ..Glide library  is not working correctly..i waste  my  two days on Glide  library  but i  find nothing..

Comment: You need to break what you are trying to do in to steps in order to find which one is failing. That way you'll most likely discover the error for yourself. That's what debugging is.

Comment: placeholder()  is not resolve    ....here is problem Glide.with(context).load(profilePicList.get(position)).into(holder.profileImage);